# How would one find out how deep a certain leaf node is in a composite design pattern?

Tags: java

For example: a folder is a composite object, and a file is a leaf.

```
Folder 1
-- Folder 2
--- File 1
```

Here i know that File 1 is three levels deep in the composite of Folder 1. What methods could I make so that I can keep track of how deep File 1 is?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Please add your code to the question and explain specifically where you are stuck.

Comment: *What methods could I make so that I can keep track of how deep File 1 is?* You would start at the target (File 1) and work your way up. Once the top of the "tree" is reached, you now know the depth of the target.

Answer (score 0):

Image this classes(`Component` is parent class that just define methods)

```
    class Leaf : Component
{
    public int deep;
    public override void Operation()
    {
        console.WriteLine("Leaf");
    }
}
```

And for composite:

```
    class Composite : Component
{
    public int deep;
    protected List<Component> _children = new List<Component>();
    
    public override void Add(Component component)
    {
        this._children.Add(component);
    }
    public override void Operation()
    {
        foreach (Component component in this._children)
        {
            component.Operation();
            component.deep = component.deep+1;
        }
    }
}
```

The main idea is `component.deep = component.deep+1`; and you can access to each object deep with `deep` variable.